# Check string for multiple words (in any order)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use some VBA code to find if say *english* and *6 months* are in a cell, for example

> "Test English, 6 months"
>   6 months English

but not

> 6 months Englishman

I can only find one word, findings two separate strings in a cell

- in any order
- whole words only

is confusing me.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and the problem you have encountered. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

*update - Bulletproofed*

```
Function StrCheck2(rng1 As Range, str1 As String, str2 As String) As Boolean
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Pattern = "^(?=.*\b" & str1 & "\b)(?=.*\b" & str2 & "\b).*$"
    .ignorecase = True
     StrCheck2 = .test(rng1.Value2)
End With
End Function
```

You could do something like this

```
Function StrCheck(rng1 As Range, str1 As String, str2 As String) As Boolean
If InStr(rng1.Value2, str1) > 0 Then
    If InStr(rng1.Value, str2) > 0 Then StrCheck = True
End If
End Function
```

Separating the two IFS allows for an early exit if the first string is not found.

You would call it like
`=StrCheck(A1,"English","6 months")`

or to avoid partial word matches
=`StrCheck(A1," English "," 6 months ")`
which would still need tinkering for an edge case of where *English* could be the first word

A `Regexp` probably the best step for a bullet-proof check.